# When was the original version of the DICE C compiler for the Amiga released? And when did it become free?

Tags: history, programming, amiga

Back in the day I bought SAS/C for the Amiga. I seem to recall that before that there was Aztec C, Manx C, and Lattice C that were the major commercial C compilers for the platform. I never used them.

At some point there appeared a great homebrew C compiler called DICE. At least I think it was what we would call homebrew since it was made by one guy, [Matt Dillon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_Dillon). (Correct me if I'm wrong.)

I'm not sure if it was released at the end of the '80s or a couple of years into the '90s. I'm pretty sure it was during the A500+A2000 era and before the AGA chipset. But I can't find anything online about its early history.

I believe it went freeware or open source at some point, perhaps after most people started moving away from the Amiga in the 486 era?

So when was DICE C first released, and when did it become free? Did DICE come out before gcc was ported to the Amiga?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you said, there were two dominant commercial C compilers for the Amiga in the late-80s: Manx Aztec C and Lattice C. Lattice C later was acquired by SAS and renamed to SAS/C. These two competed for Amiga developer share, and both were pretty expensive, as compilers tended to be at that time. I recall paying about $500 in 1988/89 for a bare-bones version of Aztec C to run on an Amiga 1000 with two floppy drives.

At the same time, Matt Dillon, while a student at Berkeley, was also a quite prolific publisher of public domain/freeware software for the Amiga. He was well-known because the Amiga had a vibrant scene for freeware and his programs were always top-notch. I recall early versions of DICE C being available in 1991. This was a welcome addition because it was initially free and was similar in capabilities to Manx Aztec C and SAS/C. As I recall, I stuck with Aztec C because it had a more capable debugger at that time.

Even though my personal recall places the beginnings of DICE C at 1991, there is text that reads "Copyright 1990 by Matt Dillon" in some of the files in the v1.15 archive of DICE - found [here](http://apollo.backplane.com/FreeSrc/). In addition, you can find this text on that same page: "This is the DICE C compiler suite which I wrote as shareware for the Amiga in the early 90's." Presumably, that statement was written by Dillon when he updated the licensing recently to be open source, BSD.

Comment: I'd put it at 1991 too: to my eternal shame, I wrote a really badly-researched review of Matt's compiler for (I think) Just Amiga Monthly. Commodore (UK) wouldn't supply the "Includes & Autodocs" required to make the compiler useful to individuals, so you already had to have either Aztec or Lattice C to make DICE work.